# How to custom deserialize into an object with json.net

Tags: json, json.net

I used http://json2csharp.com/ to generate a csharp class that represents my JSON, which worked wonderfully.  However, after working with the third party api for a while, I realized that their responses aren't always sending the same type of data.  I'm querying their API for Ticket data, and each ticket has a SellPrice.  Sometimes they return that SellPrice as a Money object that has a currency (string) and amount (double), and sometimes they send it back as just a double.  So I'm trying to find a way to handle this gracefully, so that I always set the Amount of my SellPrice object.  Here's a short version of the code that works when they send a Money object as SellPrice

```
public class Ticket
{
    public string Ticket_Id {get; set;}
    //... other fields
    public SellPrice SellPrice {get; set;}
}
public class SellPrice
{
    public string Currency {get; set;}
    public double Amount {get; set;}
}
```

And then when I get the Json, I deserialize like so, which works great...

```
for (int i = 0; i < jItems.Count; i++)
{
    TUTicket2 item = jItems[i].ToObject<TUTicket2>();
}
```

...until I run into an API call that returns a double instead of an object.

So just looking at the case where it's Money object, I thought I'd try to create a constructor so that I can set the values depending on the object type, like so:

```
public class SellPrice
{
    public SellPrice(object sellPrice)
    {
        if (sellPrice.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<string, object>))
        {
            Currency = (string)((Dictionary<string, object>)sellPrice)["Currency"];
            Amount = (double)((Dictionary<string, object>)sellPrice)["Currency"];
        }
    }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

But that doesn't work because the sellPrice object is always null, so I think I'm barking up the wrong tree there.  Is there a way to do this easily?  I think my problem is the way it auto-deserializes to an object type, but I've been looking through the code/documentation and haven't figured out what I'm missing.

I have a couple goals here:  We are doing enough API work that I'd like to be able to utilize a tool like json2csharp to generate the classes.  I'd also like to avoid doing manual deserialization for every class/object, although if that's my only option, I can go in that direction, it just feels like overkill when 99% of the values behave normally.  I also don't want to end up with X different versions of each of my classes depending on which API call I make.  I'm trying to find some solution that just lets me override a small portion instead of everything.  Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this by making a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) for your `SellPrice` class like this:

```
public class SellPriceConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(SellPrice);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        SellPrice sellPrice = new SellPrice();
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            serializer.Populate(token.CreateReader(), sellPrice);
        }
        else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Float)
        {
            sellPrice.Amount = (double)token;
            // if there is a default currency, set it here, e.g.:
            // sellPrice.Currency = "USD";
        }
        else
        {
            throw new JsonException("Unexpected token type for SellPrice: " + token.Type.ToString());
        }
        return sellPrice;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use it, all you would need to do is add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to the `SellPrice` class like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(SellPriceConverter))]
public class SellPrice 
{
    ...
}
```

Then you can just deserialize as normal and it should handle both situations.

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qZekyp

Comment: I was hoping there was something more simple, but I had a feeling this was the direction I would need to go.  Thanks a lot for the concrete solution as well.